# Docker-compose internal communication using endpoints

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Working on getting two different services running inside a single `docker-compose.yml` to communicate w. each other within `docker-compose`.

The two services are regular NodeJS servers (`app1` & `app2`). `app1` receives `POST` requests from an external source, and should then send a request to the other NodeJS server, `app2` w. information based on the initial `POST` request.

The challenge that I'm facing is how to make the two NodeJS containers communicate w. each other w/o hardcoding a specific container name. The only way I can get the two containers to communicate currently, is to hardcode a url like: `http://myproject_app1_1`, which will then direct the `POST` request from `app1` to `app2` correctly, but due to the way Docker increments container names, it doesn't scale very well nor support potential container crashing etc.

Instead I'd prefer to send the `POST` request to something along the lines of `http://app2` or a similar way to handle and alias a number of containers, and no matter how many instances of the `app2` container exists Docker will pass the request one of the running `app2` containers.

Here's a sample of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  app1:
    image: 'mhart/alpine-node:6.3.0'
    container_name: app1
    command: npm start

  app2:
    image: 'mhart/alpine-node:6.3.0'
    container_name: app2
    command: npm start

  # databases [...]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This is two questions.

**First: how to don`t hardcode container names.**
you can use system [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)  like:

nodeJS file:

```
app2Address = process.env.APP2_ADDRESS; 
response = http.request(app2Address);
```

docker compose file:

```
app1:
  image: 'mhart/alpine-node:6.3.0'
  container_name: app1
  command: npm start
  environment: 
   - APP2_ADDRESS: ${app2_address}

app2:
  image: 'mhart/alpine-node:6.3.0'
  container_name: app2
  command: npm start
  environment: 
   - HOSTNAME: ${app2_address}
```

and .env file like:

```
app2_address=myapp2.com
```

also you can use wildcard application config file. And when container starts you need to substitute real hostname.
for this action you need create entrypoint.sh and use "sed" like:

```
sed -i '/sAPP_2HOSTNAME_WILDCARD/${app2_address}/g /app1/congig.js
```

Second. how to make a transparent load balancing:

you need use http load balancer like

- [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org)
- [nginx as load balancer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

There is hello-world [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/load-balance-hello-world/) how to make a load balancing with docker

Answer (score 1):

When you run two containers from one compose file, docker automatically sets up an "internal dns" that allows to reference other containers by their `service` name defined in the compose file (assuming they are in the same network). So this should work when referencing `http://app2` from the first service.

See this example proxying requests from `proxy` to the backend `whoamiapp` by just using the service name.

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://whoamiapp;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
        - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    ports:
    - "80:80"

  whoamiapp:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
```

Run it using `docker-compose up -d` and try running `curl <dockerhost>`.

This sample uses the default network with docker-compose file version 2. You can read more about how networking with docker-compose works here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Probably your configuration of the `container_name` property somehow interferes with this behaviour? You should not need to define this on your own.