# Docker-Compose API Call and Endpoint Containerized

Tags: web-services, docker, go, docker-compose

Using docker-compose I've got multiple containers running - one of them is the profiler container that calls an API, the other container apiconnection should be receiving the call and sending information back. However when I run the compose file it always returns `Get http://apiconnection:8080/maccaption: dial tcp: lookup apiconnection on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host` on the Profiler container at the `http.DefaultClient.Do` line.

This is a sample of my compose file:

```
apiConnection:
 image: apiconnection:1.0
 ports:
  - "8080:8080"
 networks: 
  - maccaptionNet
profiler:
  image: profiler:1.0
  networks: 
   - maccaptionNet
  depends_on:
   - "apiConnection"
```

I'm calling the api in my profiler image like so - it's erroring on `DefaultClient`:

```
url := "http://apiconnection:8080/maccaption"

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Line 27")
    log.Fatal(err)
}

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Line 33")
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

If I modify the `url := "http://apiconnection:8080/maccaption"` to look at localhost like this `url := "http://localhost:8080/maccaption"` it changes to `connect refused`, but I don't think I should be looking at localhost, I need to look at the Docker container don't I?

I'm setting the url as a connection to the docker container and using the ports I've assigned in the docker-compose file. 
and receiving the request in my apiconnection image like this:

```
    r := mux.NewRouter()

r.HandleFunc("/maccaption", handleMaccaption).Methods("GET")

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
```

All it should be doing now is starting up and making a single request to prove that it is working and returning some json information. This code works outside of docker, replacing the container name in the url variable with localhost. But I cannot get it running within docker.

I've looked at these other sources for assistance but to no avail: 
[how to call api endpoint inside docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304923/how-to-call-api-endpoint-inside-docker-container)
[Making a REST Call to Endpoint in Dockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784666/making-a-rest-call-to-endpoint-in-dockers)
[Docker-compose internal communication using endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880615/docker-compose-internal-communication-using-endpoints)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

**EDIT - to fix my wonky code formatting

Comment: “I ignored the error return, and then my program panicked” is distinctly not idiomatic Go.  You need to capture the error return.  The error message will probably include something useful.

Comment: Thank you for the call out @DavidMaze - much appreciated!! It got me on the correct track with a new error message. I've modified the original question with the actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who's attempting to do something like this in the future: the above code actually *does* work. But where I was going wrong was that in my `url := "http://apiconnection:8080/maccaption"` I was referring to the image name instead of the service name I've defined in the docker-compose.

changing the url to look at the service name instead of the image name corrected the issue and I'm now able to make API calls within my dockerized environment.